# Remove model name in loop | Django ORM

Tags: python, django

My `Models.py` looks like below.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental', blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % (self.amount)

class Rental(models.Model):
    rental_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % (self.rental_id)

class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film)
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store')
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.amount)
```

I'm trying to display `rental_id` and `payment` for the given `film_id` by using following code:

```
for i in Rental.objects.filter(inventory__film_id=2).order_by("inventory_id"):
    amnt=Payment.objects.filter(rental_id= int(i.rental_id))
    print ("Rental of %s is %s") %(i, amnt)
```

and I'm getting the expected result with little unformated way as like below:

```
Rental of 10310 is [<Payment: 4.99>]
Rental of 13421 is [<Payment: 4.99>]
Rental of 4364 is [<Payment: 4.99>]
Rental of 7733 is [<Payment: 9.99>]
Rental of 15218 is [<Payment: 9.99>]
```

Help me on removing the object name `Payment` in the final result

expected result:

```
Rental of 10310 is 4.99
Rental of 13421 is 4.99
Rental of 4364 is 4.99
Rental of 7733 is 9.99
Rental of 15218 is 9.99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in Rental.objects.filter(inventory__film_id=2).order_by("inventory_id"):
    amnt=Payment.objects.filter(rental_id= int(i.rental_id))
    print ("Rental of %s is %s") %(i, amnt[0].amount)
```

Since an object of payment is returned to you, you have to mention which field you are going to display.

Comment: I have tried that, but it gives you an error as `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'amount'`

Comment: try the updated one now. filter return a list of objects

Comment: If this helped you out, please accept this as the right answer.

Comment: Worked, thanks ! sorry for the delayed response, busy weekends.